# Estimation of Beam Displacement from Acceleration

Tags: beam, dynamics, vibration

Hi Engineering Exchange,

I have a beam with pinned-pinned boundary conditions (free to rotate but not free to translate). A legacy computer analysis provided me with the maximum mid-span acceleration the beam experienced. I know the mechanical properties of the beam (E, I, weight, length, area). Ideally I would have re-run the computer model to calculate the displacement, but unfortunately its lost to time.

Is there a method that can approximate the maximum mid-span displacement given that I know the:

1. Maximum acceleration
2. Mechanical properties

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume a single degree of freedom vibration of the beam as a spring and mass system and substitute beam with half of its mass concentrated at its center, which is not grossly wrong and we also assume no damping, the beam will vibrate under its natural frequency and a rough estimate of its vibration amplitude can be substituted for its deflection.

We know the spring stiffness is

$$k = \frac{48EI}{L^3} $$

Then the beam's natural frequency will be

$$\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac{k}{1/2M}}=\sqrt{\frac{2*48EI}{m*l^3}}  $$ and acceleration is

$$ \alpha = -\omega^2A*sin\omega *t$$

Maximum acceleration happens at $ \omega=n\pi$

By pluging $n=1$ And $ t= (1/*2f) $ we can calculate $A$ the amplitude or deflection.

Comment: Thank you @kamran for your response and help.

Comment: @ganondorf29, the more exact factor of substituting the distributed mass of the beam for an SDF is %49*m. Not a half